# Should I include certification logos in my resume?

Tags: professionalism, resume, certification

Is it a good idea to add the logos for the certifications I achieved at the top of my resume? Does this look professional enough to seek the attention of the recruiter?

Comment: @Lilienthal and what about certifications logos?

Comment: Consider rephrasing your question to specifically ask about including logos. In my opinion though, don't do it, especially not at the top. Your resume should stand out based on its content not its formatting. So your certifications (including year of acquisition) should definitely be listed but that should be reserved for a regular section of your resume and be done in pure text.

Comment: I see no benefit to including a certification logo in place of its name. It is not uncommon for a recruiter/tech lead/manager to know the certification without knowing its logo. If they don't recognize the logo, your efforts go wasted. You have probably read some BS article which tells about "enhancing" your resume into a "creative" resume. They even offer to do the said enhancement for you in return for a fee. In my experience, such an enhancement only benefits *them*, not you.

Comment: I have made a drastic edit to your post to save it from the duplication flags. Feel free to expand on my edit or revert it but consider that it will probably be closed as a duplicate in its original form.

Comment: Not unless you want to look like a race car driver's uniform instead of a professional <anything except a race car driver on race day>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that most people will not see your resume in the form you are hoping for.

Most resumes today are either scanned for keywords; or are entered by cutting and pasting  it into small text boxes as part of the application process.

Using logos will mean that the keyword scanner never sees the certification, unless you also include the words. But if you include the words you are wasting real estate with the duplication of information.

Using logos when the data must be entered into the small text boxes will require you to remember to include the words because the logos can't be pasted into a text box. There is frequently given advice to paste your entire resume into a text editor to see how it looks with almost zero formatting. Your case would be a perfect example of a resume that would have a problem in text only form.

Comment: This answer seems to assume job seekers should specifically try to optimize their resumes for automated search systems. It sort of reminds me of those sites that tried to 'optimize' their search hits by including tons of keywords at the bottom of random pages. Effective at the time, perhaps. Professional? No way. As for the logos, you can easily make usability arguments in favor of text over logos. There's just no need to consider resume search engines to make this argument. Logos are pretty but not as easy for everyone to use as plain text.

Comment: It is not a matter of optimization. If the job posting specifies that you need to have certification X and Y, they will be looking for those words. A human may associate the logo with the required certifications, but the computer might not. If the software doesn't think that you have those certifications the resume may never be seen by a human.